# Explain this python code from a newbies book

Tags: python

this is my first post!
I just started learning coding python on my raspberry pi with this amazing book:
"Learning Python with Raspberry Pi"

I started with the basic chapters and then there was the summery exercise.
there are things there that wasnt covered in the previous chapter and I would like your help understanding the flow of the code.

I took the liberty uploading it to my dropbox:
[click here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lym452brvyhhhyc/chapter3-student-1.py?dl=0)
and I also input the code at the end of this post

what I don't understand:

I dont understand his definitions :{
1) can you explain the flow of them?
2) what is prev_grades?

I'm breaking my head over this.

```
students = [["Ben", {"Maths": 67, "English": 78, "Science": 72}],
            ["Mark", {"Maths": 56, "Art": 64, "History": 39, "Geography": 55}],
            ["Paul", {"English": 66, "History": 88}]]

grades = ((0, "FAIL"),(50, "D"),(60,"C"),(70, "B"), (80,"A"), (101, "CHEAT!"))

def print_report_card(report_student = None):
    for student in students:
        if (student[0] == report_student) or (report_student == None):
            print("Report card for student ", student[0])            
            for subject, mark in student[1].items():
                for grade in grades:
                    if mark < grade[0]:
                        print(subject, " : ", prev_grade)
                        break
                    prev_grade = grade[1]


def add_student(student_name):
    global students
    for student in students:
        if student[0] == student_name:
            return "Student already in database"
    students.append([student_name, {}])
    return "Student added sucessfully"

def add_mark(student_name, subject, mark):
    global students
    for student in students:
        if student[0] == student_name:
            if subject in student[1].keys():
                print(student_name, " already has a mark for ", subject)
                user_input = input("Overwrite Y/N? ")
                if user_input == "Y" or user_input == "y":
                    student[1][subject] = mark
                    return "Student's mark updated"
                else:
                    return "Student's mark not updated"
            else:
                student[1][subject] = mark
                return "Student's mark added"
    return "Student not found"

while True:
    print("Welcome the the Raspberry Pi student database")
    print("What can I help you with?")
    print("Enter 1 to view all report cards")
    print("Enter 2 to view the report card for a student")
    print("Enter 3 to add a student")
    print("Enter 4 to add a mark to a student")
    print("Enter 5 to exit")

    try:
        user_choice = int(input("Choice: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("That's not a number I recognise")
        user_choice = 0

    if user_choice == 1:
        print_report_card()
    elif user_choice == 2:
        enter_student = input("Which student? ")
        print_report_card(enter_student)
    elif user_choice == 3:
        enter_student = input("Student name? ")
        print(add_student(enter_student))
    elif user_choice ==4:
        enter_student = input("Student name? ")
        enter_subject = input("Subject? ")
        num_error = True
        while num_error:
            num_error = False
            try:
                enter_mark = int(input("Mark? "))
            except ValueError:
                print("I don't recognise that as a number")
                num_error = True
        print(add_mark(enter_student, enter_subject, enter_mark))
    elif user_choice == 5:
        break
    else:
        print("Unknown choice")
    input("Press enter to continue")
print("Goodbye and thank you for using the Raspberry Pi Student database")
```

Comment: Done! you can look at it now direcly

Comment: And what exactly do you not understand?

Comment: like i said, i dont understand the flow of his definitions

Comment: There are just several methods defined for each of the possible inputs. The inputs are asked in a infinite loop until you input an 5. Not sure what you mean by "flow"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to this link: http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit  paste your code and press the Visualize Execution, i think you will understand everything.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!
this was the most helpful since im sure its hard for people to describe the flow of te code to me.